# Why do registration flows ask for anything at all?

Tags: forms, registration, simplicity

Why not let the user in right away and trust them implicitly?

They can always register later, once they know they are in the right place and want to save their stuff longer term.

This would be a fast way to quickly get humans on board before they care about your product (they never do before signing up and seeing what your offers are). The way I see it, if well executed, this would get my attention.

I think of this kind of like *Confirm vs Undo* (I'm on the *"Undo is almost always strictly better"* camp)

Why is this a bad idea? Or, is it?

Comment: (1) It strips the user of any personal identity, which people like, and (2) the conversion rate on changing any of those values would likely be very low and you would end up with 10 accounts per user (they'd probably just stop visiting after 2-3 times).

Comment: To clarify, are you asking about doing this when someone clicks a register button? Or are you asking about doing this for everyone who's doing something? In the former case, why randomly create the username/password, when by clicking "register" they already indicate they want a relationship? In the latter case, why register at all?

Comment: Guest logins can be useful in such cases.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, your question has many issues. Relying on cookies is a no-no, cookies are a tool, not an UX process.

But more important, let's assume we can solve all the technicalities (we can't. It's as simple as visiting the page from a different device or browser, but let's say we magically can). Now you're talking on a whole different philosophy. Please follow me on this:

When I build a site, I'm doing it for a reason: communicate something, make a sale, promote a site, make people click a banner, get a mail address, whatever. Basically, I'm building an interactive result that should provide a feedback / effect. And all my efforts should aim to narrow choices so that effect is as successful as possible. However, in your scenario I should negate that, like so:

UNKNOWN VISITOR GETS TO SITE --> UNKNOWN VISITOR GETS A RANDOM ID, NO INTERACTION --> UNKNOWN VISITOR REMAINS UNKNOWN AND THERE'S NO VISIBLE EFFECT OF HIS/HER VISIT

I'm sure you'll notice the issues at first sight. And I'm not even starting on the side effects of "invading" an user and not letting choose an identity. Instead, you do it all, you decide for him/her and you provide him/her a random user and pass he/she will never remember. And of course, there's no way to get that user and pass back

Well, the above is just a small tiny sample of the reasons NOT to do what you say. ANd quite frankly, can't even think of a real reason to do it

Comment: can you imagine visiting a mall and outside of each shop is a person politely asking you for your name and nothing else before letting you in?

Comment: @DaveAlger Can you imagine visiting a mall and having someone outside of each shop politely giving you a nametag with a random name on it? That's what random registration is closer to; random username/password is very different from not having forced registration at all and not tracking the user across sessions unless they decided to do an optional registration.

Comment: i simply think that asking anything of a user before they can use your product isn't necessary.  they will tell me who they are once they realize they found the right place.

Comment: @DaveAlger: I think you missed the whole intention of my answer. The minute the person went to the mall, you already achieved a part of what you wanted. To the very minimum, you exposed the user to a myriad of stimuli, and that's just a start. You're being exposed to ads, products, all kind of visual and aural stimuli, you're being tracked with your cellphone, you're presented with offers that you may choose to buy at that moment or at a later time, the user has an intentionality and so on. What I'm describing is the EXACT OPPOSITE of this situation: user does NOTHING and remains unknown

Comment: And by the way, I don't need the users to tell me they have found the right place based on some subjective view. I NEED to convince the users THIS is the right place no matter what their subjectivity says. It's the whole foundation of advertisement. As an example: From an objective point of view 10 years ago, Twitter would be the most moronic service ever and nobody would give a dime for that. Now you would beg for a piece of the pie, and any user would go berserk if the service goes down. Objectively, Twitter is exactly the same. The subjective view has changed

Answer (score 1):

This is a good UX question so go ahead and vote it up now.  I believe that there is already a trend moving in this direction.

Reasons to skip a registration flow are...

### 1. Remove Barriers to Entry

Can you imagine visiting a mall and outside of each shop is a person politely asking you for your name and nothing else before letting you in? Sure it's nice and can be the start of a meaningful relationship but how many people buying pants at the GAP really want a relationship?

[I don't want a relationship I just want pants](http://www.uie.com/articles/three_hund_million_button/)!

### 2. Play the game first and shake hands later

Many parts of an application can be used even without knowing who is doing it.  If done right, a user will really like the interaction she is having and want to save his work at which point she will gladly hand over an email address.

Comment: I won't discuss implementation details here but am working on an open source way to reliably remember who you are and what you have done without relying on cookies.

Comment: here is part of it  --  http://codepen.io/run-time/full/XJNXWV/

Comment: However, if I'm going to be doing something long-term at a store (e.g. getting a frequent shopper card), I *expect* them to ask for name, address, and phone number. I can't really think of a case where you'd give someone a randomly generated username and password to ease barriers to registration where it wouldn't be better to just not register them at all.

Comment: yeah i don't believe in giving people random identification either - if there is a way to simply remember a face i'm all for that

Comment: i totally agree that randomly registering people is worse than asking people to register up front while asking people to register up front is worse than making registration optional.

Comment: Dave, teh question is assuming you already have a registration process, which is a totally different (and previous) question: whether you want to have a registration process or not. Your approach is nifty and totally doable, but you want to keep the "user invisibility", while I'm telling "stop hiding, I want to know who you are, where you came from, what's your age, who are your friends and so on". (Either I'm trying to sell something to that user or I'm a pervert looking for a weird date!)

Answer (score 1):

Question should be "**how can we improve the registration flow so that it's less painful?**" rather than "**can we remove the registration flow altogether?**".

This is because, not all companies have the same business model. Therefore the needs of each website will differ based on their business model and what services they are providing:

> **1. Registration is Required: E.g Netflix.com**
>
> Registration is an integral part of their business model because of
>   the nature of their business where the content has restrictions from
>   various Studios.
>
> **2. Registration is Optional: E.g Youtube.com**
>
> Users are free to browse and watch, but if they want to create
>   playlists, add videos into their watchlist then they need to register
>   an account.
>
> **3. No Registration: E.g Techmeme.com**
>
> Most news websites do not have registration feature. Because they want
>   their content to be as far reaching and viral as possible (rather than
>   protecting it behind a login process).

Comment: this is a great answer.  it's not so much that trying to get to know your users and collect information about them so that you can serve them better is a bad thing.  it's that in certain situations it can be a costly mistake.  --  don't make me register until it makes sense to do so (youtube)

Answer (score 0):

Cookies/sessions are not reliable. Nothing can guarantee that users keep them for reasonable times. Some users also have disabled cookies on their browsers.

After all, I don't think we need authentication users before that really care about our products. That's a business centered approach that they want to know more about users before a real purchase.

Let the user to place an order, ask for an email (or use an OpenID),  let them to pay, then ask them for necessary information.